# How to keep different colors on tab's background in android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I want to change the background color of the tab. for e.g if there are three tabs on single activity then need to keep different colors on that three tabs. Please anyone can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below link for your requirement:

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-change-tab-bar-background-color/

It sets default colors on startup as well change color on tab change if you want to implement that too.

thanks your upvote would be appreciated back :)

Comment: I am not using TabHost. I am using tablayout,so that link wasn't helpfull to me